# HTML code to invoke Azure automation runbook webhook

Tags: html, ajax, azure

Trying to invoke two webhooks that I've defined on a runbook in an azure automation account.

I can run the webhook through powershell, and it works, but i'm having trouble getting it to run.  Below is the code i'm using

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>Jumpbox Power</TITLE>
<BODY>
<CENTER>


<SCRIPT>
function startjumpbox() {
    var _url = 'https://s5events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=asdf;
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: _url
    })
};

function startjumpbox() {
 var _url = 'https://s5events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=fdsa';
 return $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: _url
 })
};
</SCRIPT>

Start / Stop jumpbox<br>
<button onclick="startjumpbox()">Start Jumpbox</button> 
<button onclick="stopjumpbox()">Stop Jumpbox</button
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The idea is that when the first button is pressed, the 'startjumpbox' function is run, which generates a post request to the webhook URL.  same goes for the second button and a post to the second webhook URL.
Would appreciate any advise.

Comment: You just wanna start the 2 runbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the code below. It works at my side, just reference the jquery lib(You can also download it to local and then reference it):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<head>
<TITLE>Jumpbox Power</TITLE>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<BODY>

<SCRIPT>
function startjumpbox() {
    alert("start call 1")
    var _url = 'https://s4events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=your_token';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url
    });
    alert("completed call 1")
}

function startjumpbox2() {
    alert("start call 2")
    var _url = 'https://s4events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=your_token';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url
    });
    alert("completed call 2")
}
</SCRIPT>

Start / Stop jumpbox<br>
<button onclick="startjumpbox()">Start Jumpbox</button> 
<button onclick="startjumpbox2()">Start Jumpbox2</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Excellent - worked like a charm.  Thank you!  So was my biggest problem that I didn't have the top 'script' reference to the library?

Comment: yes, you can download it to local or just use the link.